# Simple Estimates vs Model for calculating mean and variance of population

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a univariate data set that's approximately normally distributed. I am happy to assume that the population is normally distributed, and I'd like to estimate the mean and variance of the population.

My textbook suggests (as I understand it) that since my sample size is large (1000's of data points), it is reasonable to take the sample mean and sample variance as my estimates for the population sample/variance.

However, I'm also vaguely aware that regression can be used to fit a model to data. So in the case of my problem, which is a more reasonable approach (and why?):

- Just use the sample mean/variance values as estimates for the population mean/variance
- Fit the data to a normal model and use the calculated mean/variance.

Comment: It's unclear how "regression" could be invoked in a *univariate* dataset.  Also, exactly what distinction are you suggesting between the two bulleted methods?

Comment: I accept that the question might make very little sense - I admit I'm confused! In terms of regression, I imagine that you would input the formula for the normal distribution into some application that can handle non-linear regression, with the mean and variance being parameters of that formula. You would then let the application attempt to derive the values for those parameters that maximise the fit of your data to the formula. So I see that as a completely different approach than just using the sample mean/variance as estimates.

Comment: if you have no predictor variables, there would be no way to fit a non-linear model, or any model other than 'data has a mean and variance'

Comment: @Bio.X2Y: one of the points your respondents are making is that one "fits...a normal model" to the data by estimating the mean and standard deviation.  These become the mean and sd of the fitted normal distribution.  The other point they are making is that "regression" in your case means performing a least-squares fit of a constant to the data ("no covariates") and that's exactly the same as using the usual mean and sample standard deviation estimates.  So the short answer is, both approaches are reasonable and they're the same.

Comment: OK, am I right in thinking that the model you're suggesting is a linear one with no predictors, where the error is normally distributed? Isn't that different from a model where you use two predictors for mean and variance, regardless of the error?

Comment: @Bio.X2Y I think you make a confusion between (a) estimating the mean and variance from an observed sample (which is strictly an univariate problem as @whuber said), while being happy with an underlying gaussian assumption, and (b) check how well your distribution fit a theoretical distribution, with unknown mean and variance. Neither of these cases call for a modeling approach. Maybe @David can update his response for (b), otherwise the first one was already suggested to you: just use the arithmetic mean (which is an unbiased estimator) and SD (I let others discuss the denominator issue).

Comment: thanks chl. Yes, I think I understand the (a) option (and the n-1 vs n in the denominator), and my confusion lies with the (b) option. I suppose I don't understand why (b) *doesn't* call for a modeling approach - surely since the theoretical distribution has an unknown mean and variance, these have to be 'estimated' before a fit can be established. So the output to (b) would be something like "mean =1, sd=2, r^2=0.94"? Thanks again

Comment: @Bio.X2Y No, checking how an empirical distribution departs from an hypothetical/theoretical distribution is not the same than modeling a relationship between an outcome and a potential explanatory variable, or simply fit a regression with only an intercept. In the latest case, it is even better to simply use a Quantile-Quantile plot (observed vs. gaussian) to check if your data follows an expected normal distribution (as is the assumed distribution of the residuals in your LM).

Comment: ok, thanks again chl, looks like I have a lot more background reading to do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question, and you mean using a least squares model of the form $Y=\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ these two approaches are equivalent.

A simple R example will demonstrate this:

```
#generate pseudo-data
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n)

# approach 1: calculation    
sum(x)/n #mean
mse <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)/n #mse
se <- sqrt(mse/n) #std error

# approach 2: model
model <- lm(x~1)
model$coefficients[1] #mean
sqrt(sum(model$residuals^2)/n)/sqrt(n) #standard error
```

Comment: Thanks David, I suppose I was thinking of a more elaborate non-linear model, e.g. Y = (whatever it would be if the data is in normally distributed, including things like pi and the two parameters of interest, the mean and variance) + epsilon ? Sorry again if this is meaningless!

Comment: Nice example.  It might be helpful to clarify what that regression model is.  You have an intercept only regression--so you have no predictor variables.  This is precisely equivalent to a one-sample t-test for difference from 0. More simply in R: x<-rnorm(100); t.test(x); summary(lm(x~1)).  P values, SEs, estimates, intervals, etc. will all be the same.

Comment: I think there's a typo and you invert `se` and `sd`; BTW your `mse` (I assume it is mean square error) is actually the SS.

Comment: @ chi, Thanks for pointing out my error - I think its fixed

Answer (score 3):

I was about to make the same point as David, except illustrating using Stata rather than R:

```
. summarize length

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
      length |        74    187.9324    22.26634        142        233

. regress length

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  0,    73) =    0.00
       Model |           0     0           .           Prob > F      =       .
    Residual |  36192.6622    73  495.789893           R-squared     =  0.0000
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0000
       Total |  36192.6622    73  495.789893           Root MSE      =  22.266

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      length |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   187.9324   2.588409    72.61   0.000     182.7737    193.0911
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've added the bolding to highlight that the mean and standard deviation are the same as the estimate of the constant and root mean square error from a linear regression with no covariates.